# Start Glassfish Domain with java agent attached

Tags: java, glassfish, asadmin

For some monitoring purposes I need to start Glassfish domain with custom java agent attached.
If I start domain directly with command:

```
java -cp /path/to/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain bla-bla-bla -javaagent:/path/to/agent.jar
```

it works as expected.

But how to do the same with domain, which starts with asadmin?
I've tried asadmin create-jvm-options and asadmin create-system-properties - it didn't help me. Any ideas?

Comment: The `create-jvm-options` should be working. What does `list-jvm-options`say to you? Have you restasted the domain?

Comment: Actually I don't have a GF instance in front of me, but you can check the startup scripts of the Glassfish, probably there is an environment variabla e.g. `JAVA_OPTS` or similar where you can set it.

Comment: Well. I'm starting asadmin directly via admin-cli.jar.

Comment: But anyway, restarting of domain helps. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to make a wrapper then, and you can set your agent jar in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting the domain.

If you set anything JVM-related, that will not be effective until you restart the domain. The GF Admin Console also warns about it it you do it on the web UI.

The [`asadmin` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gepzd.html#scrolltoc) also warns about it.